# Permanent of a complete graph with negative cliques

Tags: permanent

Let $K_n$ be the complete graph on $n$ vertices. Inside $K_n$ there are $k$ negative(edge weight is equal to -1) complete subgraphs $K_{n_1}, K_{n_2},...,K_{n_k}$, which are vertex disjoint. Let $A(G)$ denotes the adjacency matrix of graph $G$. What will be the permanent of $A(K_n)$?. With suitable relabeling of vertices we can write

$A(K_n)=\begin{bmatrix}
-A(K_{n_1}) & \\
& -A(K_{n_2})& & J\\
& & \ddots\\
J ^T& & & A(K_m)
\end{bmatrix},$
where, $m=n-\sum_{i=1}^{k}n_i$ and $J$ denote space filled with all 1.

Answer (score 4):

I have taken the time to do some computations which I will share here and give a partial answer which deals with the second easiest special case (the easiest special is just the adjacency matrix of $K_n$ and the permanent just gives the number of derangements). Let us consider the case $k = 1$ and relabel things so I have
$$A_{m,n} = \begin{bmatrix} -A(K_m) & J &\\ J^T & A(K_n) \end{bmatrix}.$$
I will give a formula which allows one to compute the permanent of such matrices. However, there is still much I do not understand about even this simplified version. I will end with a conjecture on the sign of such permanents.

Let $[n] = \{1,2,\dots, n\},$ and let $D_{n,k}$ denote the number of injections $f: [k] \to [n]$ with $f(i) \neq i$ for $i \in [k]$ (hence $D_{n,n}$ is the derangement number). By a usual inclusion-exclusion argument
$$D_{n,k} =  \sum_{j = 0}^k (-1)^j \binom{k}{j}(n-j)_{k-j}$$
where $(x)_k = x(x-1) \cdots (x-k+1)$ is the falling factorial. Then
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{perm}\, A_{m,n} &= \sum_{k \geq 0} (-1)^{m-k} \binom{m}{k} \binom{n}{k} (k!)^2 D_{m,m-k} D_{n,n-k}\\
&= \sum_{k \geq 0} (-1)^{m-k} (m)_k (n)_k D_{m,m-k} D_{n,n-k}
\end{align*}$$
since we can choose $k$ elements to move outside of each the $K_m$ and $K_n$ blocks and distribute them in any way while "deranging" the remaining elements within each block.

Exact values of $\mathrm{perm}\, A_{m,n}$ are still elusive, but the falling factorials make it relatively easy to compute $\mod d$ (for small $d$). For example, we can compute $\mod 4.$ I omit any proof because it is just grinding out various cases (full disclosure I did not work out every case in detail, but I did enough to be convinced).

> **Proposition:** $$\mathrm{perm}\, A_{m,n} \equiv \begin{cases}  1 \mod 4 & \mathrm{if\;} (m+n) \equiv 0 \mod 2\\ 0 \mod 4 & \mathrm{if\;} (m+n) \equiv 1 \mod 4\\ 2 \mod 4 & \mathrm{if\;} (m+n) \equiv 3 \mod 4\end{cases}$$

It also seems for $\mathrm{perm}\, A_{n,n}$ the signs follow a pattern $\mod 4$ which has been checked up to $n = 100.$

> **Conjecture:** For $n > 2.$ If $n \equiv \{0,1\} \mod 4,$ then $\mathrm{perm}\, A_{n,n} > 0.$ If $n \equiv \{2,3\} \mod 4,$ then $\mathrm{perm}\, A_{n,n} < 0.$

Here are the first few values given as $n : \mathrm{perm}\, A_{n,n}.$

$$
\begin{align*}
3 &: -31\\
4 &: 593\\
5 &: 51089\\
6 &: -1760591\\
7 &: -303748271\\
8 &: 20232019681\\
9 &: 5565337120097\\
10 &: -604629434442079\\
11 &: -243755297213381119\\
12 &: 39243133773219077041\\
13 &: 21827550884874516237169\\
14 &: -4881377047864505438000687\\
15 &: -3584142541549182471478806031\\
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Using John Machacek's notation, which differs from the OP's, application of [Ryser's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent#Computation) gives
$$\mathrm{perm}\; A_{m,n}
  = \sum_{s=0}^m \sum_{t=0}^n (-1)^{s+t} \binom ms\binom nt
    (t-s+1)^s (t-s)^{m-s} (t+s-1)^t (t+s)^{n-t}.$$
It might readily simplify to John's formula; I didn't try.  I don't see how to reduce it to a 1-dimensional sum.

The case with $k$ blocks instead of 2 blocks can be written as a similar $k$-fold sum by the same method.